# I keep getting a naming error when i try to run this piece of code (Python)

Tags: python, class

```
class game_type(object):
    def __init__(self):
        select_game = raw_input("Do you want to start the game? ")
        if select_game.lower() == "yes":
            player1_title = raw_input("What is Player 1's title? ").lower().title()


class dice_roll(object,game_type):
    current_turn = 1
    current_player = [player1_title,player2_title]
    def __init__(self):
        while game_won == False and p1_playing == True and p2_playing == True: 
            if raw_input("Type 'Roll' to start your turn  %s" %current_player[current_turn]).lower() == "roll":
```

I keep getting an error which reads: 
    NameError: name 'player1_title' is not defined

I understand that title is a function so i did try using player1_name and player1_unam but these also returned the same error :(

can somebody please help

All answers are greatly appreciated

Comment: The class initializer is not really the best place for that kind of user interaction. You could create a function to get that, and provide them to the class as parameters.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of things leading to the NameError.

For one, the `__init__` method of game_type does not save any data. To assign instance variables you have to specify the class instance with `self.`. If you don't, you're just assigning local variables.

Secondly, you must explicitly call a parent class's `__init__` function with `super()` if you are creating a new one in a child class and still want the effects of the parent's.

So basically, your code should be

```
# Class names should be CapCamelCase
class Game(object):                                                                
    def __init__(self):                                                    
        select_game = raw_input("Do you want to start the game? ")         
        if select_game.lower() == "yes":                               
            self.player1_title = raw_input("What is Player 1's title? ").lower().title()
            # Maybe you wanted this in DiceRoll?
            self.player2_title = raw_input("What is Player 1's title? ").lower().title()

# If Game were a subclass of something, there would be no need to 
# Declare DiceRoll a subclass of it as well
class DiceRoll(Game):                                                      
    def __init__(self):                                                   
        super(DiceRoll, self).__init__(self)                               
        game_won = False                                                   
        p1_playing = p2_playing = True                                     
        current_turn = 1                                                   
        current_players = [self.player1_title, self.player2_title]    
        while game_won == False and p1_playing == True and p2_playing == True:
            if raw_input("Type 'Roll' to start your turn %s" % current_players[current_turn]).lower() == "roll":
                pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have used this code and it is now returning an attribute error, it is saying that DiceRoll doesn't contain an instance of player1_title

Comment: I'm not sure why player1_title would be missing, my revision just corrected current_player not existing, and super requiring the parent to be a subclass of object.